# AngularJS 1.4 states to 1.5 components migration and how to approach component based architechure

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, components, angularjs-components

There are good articles that explains the significance of components and how to migrate existing directive to components with angularJS 1.5. I am working on a medium sized project with ui-router and nested states. Each state comprising of a controller and template.
My question is that why don't any article mentions about migrating existing states(with a controller+template) to a component? Am I going in a wrong direction? I understand that directives are good use cases for migration, but aren't all states supposed to be a components going forward with component based architecture? 
Are there any examples out there with existing projects migrated to 1.5 components? Please advice.

Edit: Found this article resourceful https://github.com/toddmotto/angular-styleguide#one-way-dataflow-and-events

Comment: is quite trivial to convert a state `templateUrl` to a component or directive `template`. For example in abstract states it's not uncommon to do `template':'<ui-view>'`